# Find & Replace in bulk, but the phrases have commas

Tags: vba, ms-word

I tried a bulk find & replace, but my phrases have commas in them.

I used a few snippets I found online, such as the two examples below.

I tinkered with them a bit.

I regularly have documents where there are stutters and the speaker says "the, the" or "and, and" etc.
I've a list of about 15 of these repeat phrases. I'd like to replace them in bulk rather than one at a time in the normal find/replace option in Word.

```vb
Sub MultiReplace()
Dim StrOld As String, StrNew As String
Dim RngFind As Range, RngTxt As Range, i As Long
StrOld = "the,quick,brown,fox"
StrNew = "The,Quick,Brown,Fox"
Set RngTxt = Selection.Range
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrOld, ",";))
    Set RngFind = RngTxt.Duplicate
    With RngFind.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = Split(StrOld, ",")(i)
        .Replacement.Text = Split(StrNew, ",")(i)
        .Format = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

AND.... VERSION 2:

```vb
Sub FindAndReplaceMultiItems()
'Update by ExtendOffice 2018/10/25
    Dim xFind As String
    Dim xReplace As String
    Dim xFindArr, xReplaceArr
    Dim I As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xFind = InputBox("Enter items to be found here,seperated by comma: ", "Kutools for Word")
    xReplace = InputBox("Enter new items here, seperated by comma: ", "Kutools for Word")
    xFindArr = Split(xFind, ",")
    xReplaceArr = Split(xReplace, ",")
    If UBound(xFindArr) <> UBound(xReplaceArr) Then
        MsgBox "Find and replace characters must be equal.", vbInformation, "Kutools for Word"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For I = 0 To UBound(xFindArr)
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = xFindArr(I)
            .Replacement.Text = xReplaceArr(I)
            .Format = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume you copied this code from somewhere and because it uses commas to delimit the text to be searched/replaced, you cannot have commas within the text itself. The quick/dirty way to fix this would simply to replace the comma in the code with some other character that does not appear anywhere in the text like `^@` etc... A better way would be to define the arrays of text directly `myArray = Array("Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit")` instead of splitting comma delimited strings

Answer (score 1):

You could simply change the delimiter. For example:

```
Sub MultiReplace()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrOld As String, StrNew As String, i As Long
StrOld = "the|quick|brown|fox"
StrNew = "The|Quick|Brown|Fox"
With Selection.Range
  .ClearFormatting
  .Format = False
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrOld, "|";))
    .Replacement.ClearFormatt"|")(i)
    .Replacement.Text = Split(StrNew, "|")(i)
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```